# Deploy Custom Build Activity to clients

Tags: tfs

When creating Custom Build Activities for TFS 2010/2012 it results in assembly (dll) files which can be used in build definitions.

When developing locally you place the assembly in the GAC or Visual Studio probing folder. For the build controller you place the assembly in source control (TFS) and tell the controller where to look.

All fine and working nicely.

The thing is that other developers (quite a lot) on other machines will need this assembly also when starting new builds. How do you deploy new versions of this assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assemblies are retrieved from TFS source control location defined for controller to tmp folder for Visual Studio and loaded into scope when opening build definition for edit (and probably when you open queue dialog).

You need assemblies in GAC (or VS private assemblies folder) if you are editing template itself, adding xaml template to activity project allows you to bypass GAC but will mess up namespace imports in xaml resulting in errors in tfs.

Another caveat is that if your activity assembly is using another library assembly this 2nd dll may not be picked up correctly - workaround is to add a fake empty activity to library.

Comment: So you are saying when the (other) developers are queuing a new build the assembly is loaded from the controller with no hassle? I'm only referencing MS system and TeamFoundation dll's.

Comment: Yes, you can make sure it works quite easy, uninstall assemblies from GAC and open new VS instance and try to open build definition. You can also then use another VS instance to attach debuger to first instance and review loaded modules - find your assemblies in the list and see where they are being taken from. There might be small differences in 2012 but the process should be similar.